# AngularJS: Securing routes using ui-router

Tags: angularjs

I am playing around with `ui-router` for AngularJS and was wondering if anyone out there could point me in the direction of securing routes based on authorization roles.

I have looked at the `resolve` object on the state, but it seems like I am looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537311/angular-ui-router-login-authentication/22540482#comment37988970_22540482

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `$urlRouterProvider.when()` here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#urlrouterprovider

If you pass in a function (instead of a redirecting url), it is injectable. So if you inject a service that you use to manage authentication, you can redirect the user as per your requirements.