# angular ui routing for authenticated users, variable is showing undefined even when initialized as false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am modelling my routing based on this post: [angular ui-router login authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537311/angular-ui-router-login-authentication).

I am making a cordova phonegap app. I'm new to angularjs and it's quite a new learning experience so I appreciate any suggestions at all! If I'm building the authentication routing wrong please let me know.

I have 2 factories and a run method. My first factory is titled 'principal', and the most important variable is `isFBLoggedIn`. It also has has a return of 3 functions, 2 of which are initializers, one initializing [quickblox](http://www.quickblox.com) and one initializing facebook. The 3rd function just resolves and returns the promise.

The second factory is named 'authorization' and really just redirects based on whether the variable `isFBLoggedIn` is true. It is resolved in my state named 'app' which is an abstract parent state. (It has a menu template and menu controller but not sure if that matters).

The run method simply sets the `toState` and `toStateParams` and then also routes based on `isFBLoggedIn`. I'm not sure if I needed to put routes here but I assumed I did since I believe factories only run once...

So my variable `isFBLoggedIn` is coming up undefined and I cant figure out why. I've initialized it in my code...

I tried to copy as much of the code from that link because I'm not very familiar with angularjs ui. However if you believe there is a better way that I should be authenticating please let me know. I'd love to do things properly the first time and not the 10th time...

I've been sitting/looking at this too long so I'm hoping I can get some help...What am I doing wrong?

**Edit to add**: In addition to the `isFBLoggedIn` variable showing up undefined, when I type the url into my browser for a page requiring login, I see the url in the browser changing to `/login` (which is what I want/expect). However the actual view does not change. I came across this [link](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/using-state-go-to-navigate-between-views-doesnt-work-location-path-does/1846/4) which had it seems the same issue. However I don't understand what they are saying is the problem...

run method

```
.run(['$rootScope','$state','$stateParams','principal','authorization',function($rootScope,$state,$stateParams,principal,authorization){

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(event,toState,toParams,fromState,fromParams){
      $rootScope.toState = toState;
      $rootScope.toStateParams = toParams;

      // if logged in and going to login page, redirect to cards page
      if (principal.isFBLoggedIn && toState.name === 'app.login'){
        $state.go('app.cards');
      } else if (!principal.isFBLoggedIn && toState.name != 'app.login') {
        // not logged in and not going to login page, redirect to login page.
        $state.go('app.login');
      } else {
           // this is theoretically all fine but that's not true 
           // because things are being routed here because isFBLoggedIn is showing undefined.
      }

    });
  }])
```

principal factory

```
  .factory('principal',['$q','$timeout',function($q,$timeout){
    isFBLoggedIn = false;
    return {
      QBInit: function(){
        QB.init(CONFIG.application_id, CONFIG.authKey, CONFIG.authSecret, CONFIG.debug);
        QB.createSession(function(err, result) {
          if (err){
            return $q.reject("QB Create Session Error");
          } else {
            return result.token;
          }
        });
      },
      FBInit: function(){

        if (!window.cordova) {
          // first check if fb is defined and run browser init and get login status if successful
          checkFBDefined(function(){
            facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit(1506810102869030,"v2.0");
            facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(
              function(res){
                if (typeof(res) != 'undefined' && res.status === 'connected'){
                  this.isFBLoggedIn = true;
                }
                return res;
              },
              function(err){return $q.reject('getLoginStatus Error: ' + err);
            });
          },0,$timeout);

        } else {
            facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(
              function(res){
                if (typeof(res) != 'undefined' && res.status === 'connected'){
                  this.isFBLoggedIn = true;
                }
                return res;
              },
              function(err){return $q.reject('getLoginStatus Error: ' + err);
            });
        }
      },
      initialization: function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise.then(this.QBInit).then(this.FBInit);
        deferred.resolve();
        return promise;
      }
    }
  }])
```

authorization factory

```
  .factory('authorization',['$rootScope','$state','principal',function($rootScope,$state,principal){
    return {
      authorize: function(){
        return principal.initialization().then(function(){
          if (principal.isFBLoggedIn && $rootScope.toState.name == 'app.login'){
            // logged in, but going to login page, redirect to cards page
            $state.go('app.cards');
          } else if (!principal.isFBLoggedIn && $rootScope.toState.name !='app.login'){
            // not logged in and not going to login page, redirect to login page.
            $rootScope.returnToState = $rootScope.toState;
            $rootScope.returnToStateParams = $rootScope.toStateParams;
            $state.go('app.login');
          } else {
            console.log("routes should be fine but isn't because isFBLoggedIn is undefined");
          }   

        });
      }
    }
  }])
```

where authorization factory is resolved:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider

      .state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
        resolve:{authorize: ['authorization',function(authorization){
            return authorization.authorize();
            }]
        },
        controller: 'MenuCtrl'
      })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You init `isFBLoggedIn = false;` as global variable and it is not bound to factory `principal` you inject to `app.run`.

Try this:

```
.factory('principal',['$q','$timeout',function($q,$timeout){
  var isFBLoggedIn = false;
  return {
    isFBLoggedIn: isFBLoggedIn,
    QBInit: function(){ // rest of code
```

Comment: ah thank you! Now I don't have the undefined problem, I still have the problem that the url in my browser changes to the 'routed' url, but the view doesn't change. Any reason why that might be?

Comment: You should post a new question for a different question

Comment: try to use in $stateChangeStart callback `event.preventDefault()` in case you want to stop state change

Answer (score 1):

when you initialize `isFBLoggedIn` you have:

`isFBLoggedIn = false;`

I belive you want

`this.isFBLoggedIn = false;`