# ui-router: Prevent resolve to be resolved when activating a state in one of the resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In the `home` state, I have a function that checks if the current user is authorized along with other promises.

```
resolve: {
    authorize: ['AuthService', function (AuthService) {
        console.log("authorize from home");
        return AuthService.authorize();
    }],
    competitions: ['Competition', function (Competition) {
        return Competition.query();
    }]
}
```

The `AuthService.authorize` activates the `login` state if there is no user logged in.

```
var authorize = function () {
    console.log("Authorize ");
    if (!isLoggedIn()) {
        $q.when(angular.noop).then(function () {
            console.log("Not logged in, go to login state");
            $state.go('login');
        });
    }
};
```

It's working as expected the login state is activated but the `competitions` promise is resolved (I can see the REST call returning a 401 if no user logged in which is correct). Since the `authorize` resolve activates another state, is there a way to prevent the following resolve to be executed?

My implementation is based on that question: [angular ui-router login authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537311/angular-ui-router-login-authentication)

Comment: On a phone, so this is all I can type: use an parent state that is abstract. The parent state has a resolve that verifies the user is logged in.  Then create a child state that resolves the competitions. In this second resolve you can now inject the authorization resolve and use that to decide whether or not to make the competitions query.