# Avoid direct access to view(angular-ui-router) in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following configuration in my AngularJS App:

```
angular
    .module('MyApp')
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', 
        function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('start');

            $stateProvider
                .state('start', {
                    url : '/start',
                    templateUrl : 'views/start.html',
                    controller : 'AppCtrl'
                })
                .state('quotation', {
                    url : '/quotation',
                    templateUrl : 'views/quotation.html',
                    controller : 'AppCtrl'
                })
                .state('loading', {
                    url : '/loading',
                    templateUrl : 'views/loading.html'
                });
        }]);
```

When the user type http://example.net the "start" view is loaded good http://example.net/#/start, but if the user type directly http://example.net/#/quotation the "quotation" view  is loaded and there I have some problems, because the call from start to quotation load some values (via REST API), so .. If the user type directly that view, the loaded was not correct.

How I can avoid direct access to another views?

Comment: this is similar to implementing, say, authentication checks. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537311/angular-ui-router-login-authentication

Comment: Are you build a mobile app or web app?

Comment: You can check on each state change if there is any exception thrown. If so then handle it by either going to starting page or showing some error message

Answer (score 0):

In star page load change set the  `$rootscope.allowpage=true` then use the following code, it will check whether `$rootscope.allowpage` is set to true or not , if `$rootscope.allowpage` not true it will redirect to start page

```
angular.module('MyApp'['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap','timer'])
.run(function($rootScope,$location) {
        $rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
              if ( $rootScope.allowpage!= true ) {
                    $location.path('start');
              }});
});
```