# ng-token-auth and route permissions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

Currently I'm implementing `ng-token-auth` into my Angular application, while this works great, I'm having some trouble with restricting access to certain pages.

In some of my routes I have a couple of extra parameters:

```
data: {
    title: 'Dashboard',
    restricted: true, // Only allow logged in users
    role: 2 // Only allow a specific role
}
```

I'm doing this checking login in `$stateChangeStart`, so before I switch routes, I can check if the user is allowed to that route.

I followed the `ng-token-auth` suggestions about using a parent route with a resolve to check if a user is logged in or not:

```
resolve: {
    auth: function($auth) {
        console.log('validate user');

        return $auth.validateUser();
    }
}
```

Now the problem comes when I first load up the application, obviously the `$stateChangeStart` event is fired before the `$auth.validateUser()` has been resolved, because of that the login inside the `$stateChangeStart` fails and the user is redirected to the login page.

What would be the better way of implementing this "permissions logic", I don't want to do it per route, as that would add in a lot of extra work and code.

Doing it in the `$stateChangeStart` also doesn't seem to be the best options as that doesn't work on first load.

Comment: Why can't you check `auth` in `$stateChangeSuccess`? `$stateChangeSuccess` would only be fired, AFAIK, when all `resolve` promises are resolved, including `auth`.

Comment: @NewDev I could do that, but other routes have more `resolve` promises, I'm not sure if I should be making the user load extra data for something he can't access.

Comment: Actually, forget about `$stateChangeSuccess`. Take a look at this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22540482/968155) instead

Comment: @NewDev That link helped me a lot, thanks for that! I used the example that they provided and implemented it into my own application and it seems to do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I would treat `Authentication` and `Authorization` as two different things.

`ng-token-auth` helps you with Authentication. It even helps you with selecting which routes must be available for authenticated users Refer to [example-using-angular-ui-router](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth#example-using-angular-ui-router)

```
role: 2 // Only allow a specific role
```

seems more of authorization and permissions. For that you may want to take a different approach. One such approach. We took a similar approach - we also made sure some of the authorization was fetched upfront.