# How to skip login page if user is already logged in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on an **IONIC** application where I have checked if user is already logged in and if user is already logged then application should redirect on dashboard. This functionality is working well, but the application first showing login page for couple of seconds and then redirect to the dashboard.

**app.js**

```
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
    var prefs = plugins.appPreferences;
    prefs.fetch('iuserid').then(function (value) {
        if (value != '') {
            $state.go('app.dashboard');
        }
    });
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: "/app",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: "/login",
            templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        })
        .state('app.dashboard', {
            url: "/dashboard",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "templates/dashboard.html",
                    controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
        ;
    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    });
});
```

I don't know where I am making mistake.

**Edit:** I am able to authenticate and redirect to the dashboard but my problem is the login page displayed for few (up to 2) seconds and then redirect to the dashboard and I am working on **IONIC** application

**Second Edit**
I found the problem but don't know the solution.  Preference work greatly in $ionicPlatform.ready but do not work in $locationChangeStart. And I need preference in $locationChangeStart because it runs before $ionicPlatformReady. I desperately need the solution.

Comment: Use app.run https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Comment: @kalpeshpatel I have already tried it. It generate error "plugins is not defined" in app.run

Comment: possible duplicate of [angular ui-router login authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537311/angular-ui-router-login-authentication)

Comment: mark as solved if it is

Comment: @AlpeshTrivedi mark as solved if it works please for other mates.

Comment: @AlpeshTrivedi did you figure out the solution, this is also not working for me.

Answer (score 31):

I do the following:

in the app.js

```
.state('login', {
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl     : "templates/session/login.html",
    controller      : 'SessionCtrl'
  })

  .state('register', {
    url: "/register",
    templateUrl     : "templates/session/register.html",
    controller      : 'SessionCtrl'
  })
  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl     : "templates/menu.html",
    controller      : 'AppCtrl',
    onEnter: function($state, Auth){
        if(!Auth.isLoggedIn()){
           $state.go('login');
        }
    }
  })
  .state('app.main', {
    url: "/main",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl   : "templates/main_menu.html",
        controller    : "MainMenuCtrl"
      }
    }
  })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/main');
```

Auth is a factory, it stores the auth session in localstorage.

```
angular.module('auth.services', [])
.factory('Auth', function () {
   if (window.localStorage['session']) {
      var _user = JSON.parse(window.localStorage['session']);
   }
   var setUser = function (session) {
      _user = session;
      window.localStorage['session'] = JSON.stringify(_user);
   }

   return {
      setUser: setUser,
      isLoggedIn: function () {
         return _user ? true : false;
      },
      getUser: function () {
         return _user;
      },
      logout: function () {
         window.localStorage.removeItem("session");
         window.localStorage.removeItem("list_dependents");
         _user = null;
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: hi facing the same problem but still not working tried the abobe gettin error AuthData not defined

Comment: Worked perfectly , Best answer

Comment: Auth.isLoggedIn() always returns false. How to set the user logged state to true. Can you be more specific on the answer.

Comment: Is there any other solution as I am getting the following issue using the above proposed solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38244716/state-go-not-working-for-nested-states  . Is there any other solution for this problem?

Comment: is `auth.services` is default module or can we define it ?

Comment: Is a custom module, I use it in order to set the logged user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should listen to the event `$stateChangeStart` on the `$rootScope`, you can listen to this event during runtime, like this:

```
angular.module("myapp.permission").run($rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        var loggedIn = true;
        if(loggedIn) {
            $state.go('app.dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the run method would run after the config method so the delay would still be there. Is there any solution that could run before the config runs

Answer (score 0):

Guys try this elegant solution:

1. if the user is not logged in and login is required it redirect to login.
2. if the user try to get to login and he already logged in, prevent him from doing it.
3. mark every path as "requireAuth" and it will work.
4. place your code in **app.js**

   ```
   .run(function ($rootScope, $location, authService) {
       $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
           if (to.requireAuth && !authService.isAuthed()) {
               $location.path("/login");
           }
           else if (to.name == 'login' && authService.isAuthed()) {
               ev.preventDefault();
               $location.path("/dashboard");
           }
       });
   })
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/loginpage')
```

at the bottom of routes.js file.

Answer (score -3):

Inside your "*run*" block and outside of *$ionicPlatform.ready* you can use this:

```
    //Check if user loggedin and redirect to login page if not

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) { 

    //Check only if you are not in login page              
    if(toState.name.indexOf('app') !== -1 ) {

      // If user is not logged, will redirect to login page, eg:
      var prefs = plugins.appPreferences;
      prefs.fetch('iuserid').then(function (value) {
         if (value != '') {
            $state.go('login');
         }
      });
    }                         

});
```

After you must change your:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

for this:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');
```

The idea is directly route to dashboard and if is not logged in, will redirect to login page.

Comment: I think this doesn't avoid seeing one page 1 second