# prevent user to access if has not logged in (only login/register views)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i am creating an app with Ionic. I need that when the user is not logged, and him go to another state/page that it is not the log/register view, the app move it to the login or register.

but my code generates a loop.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, fromState){
    if(!UserFactory.isLoggedIn() && (toState.name !== 'login' || toState.name !== 'register') ){
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('login');
    }else if(toState.name == 'login' || toState.name == 'register'){
        $state.go(toState.name);
    }
});
```

** UPDATE **

i removed the else if statement, but the problem is the same.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, fromState){
    if(!UserFactory.isLoggedIn() && toState.name !== 'login' ){
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('login');
    }
});
```

any solution?

thanks!

pd: Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Maybe you don't need second condition with $state.go(toState.name)

Comment: yes, but, how can i do to go to the register view without the app move me to the login view?

Comment: I don't understand what problem is. Do you remove else if statement?

Comment: yes but the loop continues. 

the problem is that I want the user can move in the view registration and login, if he is not login, but not in the others views.

Comment: Could you update your question with my suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916966/how-to-skip-login-page-if-user-is-already-logged-in-ionic-framework?rq=1