# How to keep user login data in to sharedpreference in ionic v1

Tags: session, ionic-framework, authentication, sharedpreferences, hybrid-mobile-app

I am a beginner ionic-v1 and I want to keep user data into share preference. This data will be used in some sections of the application. Is there any way to save this data until user not logout? And I have one another question that If user is already logged then move user to main screen of the app instead of login screen. How to implement this functionality?
This is the main things of any app. How it will be integrated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store data with application localstorage

```
window.localStorage['varname'] =$scope.datavar;
```

For already login you can use stack posted answer [How to skip login page if user is already logged in ionic framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916966/how-to-skip-login-page-if-user-is-already-logged-in-ionic-framework)