# Login Page Showed up And Logged me out

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to skip login page if user is already logged in Angular Js (version 1)...
when i press the back button it logged me out and drive me to the login
page (from the home page only)

Comment: can you be more specific ? it is too general, I guess that you log out the user on initial loading of log in page, which is wrong, there are some approaches for preventing user from visiting login page if he is log in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip login page if user is already logged in ionic framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916966/how-to-skip-login-page-if-user-is-already-logged-in-ionic-framework)

Comment: You should provide some code and explain how your environment work.

Comment: not an answerable question

Answer (score 0):

A way to go about this (I dont know how you validate if the user is logged in I am assuming you are using a session) is to check if the user has a good Session and then use $state.go to send them back to the home page.