# AngularJS + PHP Login authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a WebApp where i have a login page and also some user restrictions.
I have my app running perfect but now I'm stuck in the login process.
The WebApp is based on `AngularJs`, `PHP` and a database with `MYSQL`.

Also, I'm asking this because i didn't found any good answer or work process on the first steps of the login process. Also keep in mind I'm not an `AngularJs` advanced user, I'm still learning, so sorry if I'm making somethins stupid.

#### What i have:

Right now I have a simple login system (working) using only `PHP`, like this:

***index.php***

```
<?php session_start();
    include ('dist/php/config.php');

    if(isset($_GET['out'])){
        session_destroy();
        back("#");
    }
    if((!empty($_POST['user'])) && (!empty($_POST['password']))){

        $p = ['user'=>$_POST['user'], 'password'=>$_POST['password']];
        $r = sql("select * from users where user= :user and password = :password",$p);
        if($r != 0){
            foreach($r as $ln){
                $_SESSION['loggedin']=$ln['name_user'];
            }
        } else {
            $msg = "<div class='login_fb'><p>User or password incorrect</p></div>";
        }
    }

    if(!empty($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
        include "system.php";
    } else { ?>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    [... rest of head ...]
</head>
<body>
     [... rest of body with login form ...]
</body>
<?php } ?>
```

My routing system is controlled with `AngularJs ui-router`.

The problem this system (at least i don't know how to do it) is to keep the user data reusable even after the page refresh.

#### My objective

What i want is:

- Login into the WebApp;
- Store user data to be used in all pages; For example, it's name or it's `ID`;
- Be able to refresh the page and don't lose the logged state;
- Control the user access based on it's power level (master, admin, user, guest);
- Secure Login system;
- Prevent users to access a further page when changing the URL manually. For example: Typing webapp.com/#/order and with this they jump the login process;

I've alreay found some examples, but they are way to complex (i mean, lack of explanation or plain code), or have some of these failures. I also found [this great answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537311/angular-ui-router-login-authentication) but it already start the explanation with user logged in.

Also, i saw some reference to use $cookieStore (or just $cookie, [since it's deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore)) like this:

```
app.run(['loginService', function(loginService){
    var username = $cookieStore.get('username');
    var password = $cookieStore.get('password');
    loginService.login(username, password);
}]);
```

But is it ok to use this code? Is it safe? Because we'll have to handle the password value.

#### What i want to know

So, with this is mind, what i want to know is:

- Is it ok, recommended or is there a better option to handle the login process than the one I'm using at the momment?
- How can i prevent the users to access the `WebApp` without the login process?
- How can i store the user data to control it's access to restricted areas or to just simple show a message with his name?
- How to keep the user logged in even after the refresh?

If it's okay to stay using the same login system I'm using now, how can i keep the user information reusable trought all the other pages and also keep it reusable after a page refresh?

Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Never store users' password client side.

Comment: That was what i imagined. But how should i proced with the login system in this scenario?