# Angular 2 - Is it possible to use the new router while upgrading with the "Upgrade Adapter"

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

I am upgrading my application progressively using the Upgrade Adapter. My app uses ui-router (+ has child routes).

I read this [great article](https://auth0.com/blog/2016/01/25/angular-2-series-part-4-component-router-in-depth/?utm_content=buffer66c84&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer) about routing in Angular 2. My question is:

Is it possible to use new router while still in Angular 1.X app + Upgrade adapter?

For example:

I have an angular 1.X template with `<div ui-view=""></div>`. When I upgrade it to be Angular 2.0 component I must use the new component router with it, because Angular 2.0 is rendering this component now. But, in order to use it I should do:

```
bootstrap(App, [provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: PathLocationStrategy })])
```

Which I do not have when bootstraping with the Upgrade Adater!

Should I first move the bootstrap to be Angular 2 and only then move to the Component router?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know about UpgradeAdapter, but the code line you posted seems quite outdated. It's <= 2.0.0-RC.5. Now we are at 2.4.6.

Comment: Yep, this question is almost one and a half years old...

Comment: Sorry, the question popped up in the stream because of the edit. I didn't check the date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular ui-router login authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537311/angular-ui-router-login-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! Your component containing `ui-view` should be changed to a `router-outlet`, but otherwise, you should be able to convert your routes to AngularJS components and use them with the new RouterModule.