# AngularJs and Angular-UI-Router routes permissions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, user-permissions

I'm facing an issue on how to implement route restrictions based on remote data gotten from the server.

Suppose I have the following config file:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
      .state('post', {
        url: '/post/:post_id',
        abstract: true,
        [...]
    })
      .state('post.view', {
        url: '/view'
        [...]
    })
      .state('post.edit', {
        url: '/edit'
        [...]
    })

}]);
```

The requirements for my application are:

- A post has an owner (creator of the post) and its domain may be public or private.
- If the domain is public, every user will be able to see the post (entering state `post.view`), and, if not (domain is private), only the owner will be able to see it.
- The `post.edit` state is only accessible to the owner.

To do this, what is the best approach?

I was thinking of having a resolve promise that fetches the data from the server (post's domain and correspondent user role), performs the required checks and returns accordingly (promise resolved or rejected).

But then, how would I redirect the user to a correct state if he is not authorized? For example, a common user trying to access the `post.edit` state should be redirected to the `post.view` state, if the post's domain is public... But if the post's domain is private, an unauthorized access page should be presented. Is it a good approach to do this directly on the resolve? What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at this great tutorial on routing authorization based on roles:

[role based authorization](http://arthur.gonigberg.com/2013/06/29/angularjs-role-based-auth/)

Also have a look at this stackoverflow answer, here there is conditional routing based on login, you can use the same logic of roles for your purpose,

[Ui-router, routes based on permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537311/angular-ui-router-login-authentication)

Comment: Thank you! The tutorials really helped me to get something working! But now, I have a different problem... I'm able to redirect the user accordingly, but every time a redirect happens, there is some kind of flickering (and some templates are loaded, of the unauthorised states)!

Comment: You can avoid the flickering by showing some overlay with loading icons.

Comment: Adding an overlay with loading icons is in the 'To-do list' :) I managed to get rid of some flickering using `event.preventDefault()`