# Run function before ng-init in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-init

I have a function `checkLogin()` which sets a variable in a service. This is always run in `app.run(...)`. In one function called by ng-init I want to use this variable to make a call to my backend. The problem is that ng-init is called before, so the call to my backend sends an `undefined` variable. What should I do to make sure that `checkLogin()` is always called first?

Comment: you could use `resolve` property of `state`/`route`, in that you could have `checkLogin()` method check.. so resolve will make that call before loading `templateUrl` with `controller`. you could refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22540482/2435473) for more information

Comment: You should use promises and callbacks to achieve what you want instead of `ng-init`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this Here login required is a function of service

```
.state('app.dashboard', {
      url: "/dashboard",
      templateUrl: "partials/dashboard.html",
      controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
      activePage:'dashboard',
      resolve: {
        loginRequired: loginRequired
      }
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. However, one thing doesn't work. In my index.html page I include a partial navbar.html and inject a controller homeController. However, how do I use resolve here, since it's not a route?