# What is the calling order of angularjs functions (config/run/controller)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, angular-services, angular-module

There are

- controllers
- constants
- directives
- services
- factory
- run
- config
- filters

functions of `angular.js`. What is the calling order of all these modules?

Comment: check this example https://fiddle.jshell.net/afluegge/apo91559/light/

Comment: Put 3 console.logs and find out yourself?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Learning this I made a fiddle observing the behaviour by `console.log`. Its like

- app config
- app run
- directive setup
- directive compile
- (app controller dependencies)

  - service
  - factory
  - inner factory
  - inner service
- app controller
- filter
- directive linking
- filter render (w.r.t the markup)

Observe yourself [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jsalaat/zs9jfg40/) (Check Console).

**EDIT**

New [Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jsalaat/gvq8aw3d/) with `filters` added

Comment: and filters place?

Comment: @SunilGarg Please check the updated answer. I've added a filter too.

Comment: thanks! but if i am injecting filter in the controller then the filter will get loaded first. Same with the service, if inject service in run then this will get loaded before run method.

Comment: Yes basically after `directive compile` the controllers dependencies are loaded and then the services factories filters get loaded w.r.t the dependencies which are injected in the controller.

Comment: Will this order be maintained no matter the order in wich the programmer calls these functions ?

Comment: where does components come in this order ? Angular Js 1.5 has components !

Comment: Just to add: App Constant Providers, App Value Providers are executed in same order before App config is executed

Comment: I downvote this as tthis answer is misleading... the documentation states clearly that provider functions are executed first (Value, Factory, Service, Provider, Constant) and then config and finally run blocks. You may notice that inside config or run blocks you can inject a service... that would be possible if config or run blocks are evaluated firsts. You may refer to https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#dependencies-and-order-of-execution

Comment: @Victor this is really an old answer.  and i posted this answer while i was learning angularjs. I just demonstrated the behavior of angularjs with console.logs as you see above with fiddles. but maybe this is changed now but previous it worked like that

Comment: @M.JunaidSalaat older or not people like me still find this and as long this content is reachable I guess you may amend it. Not my intention to be hard or anything, just trying to do a right thing. Greetings.