# .run starts before $http callback. Angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, transition

I'm using ui-router 1.0.0.X with it's  transitions new standart.
My code:

- Service for login, save data in storage, determine if it exist and clear

  ```
  app.factory('AuthService', ['$http', '$cookies', '$rootScope',
  function ($http, $cookies, $rootScope) {

      var service = {};

      // Authenticates throug a rest service
      service.authenticate = function (email, password, callback) {

          $http.post('endPoints/login.php', {
                  email: email,
                  password: password
              })
              .then(function (response) {

                  callback(response);        
              });
      };

      // Creates a cookie and set the Authorization header
      service.setCredentials = function (response) {

          $rootScope.globals = response;

          $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + response;
          $cookies.put('globals', $rootScope.globals);
      };

      // Checks if it's authenticated
      service.isAuthenticated = function () {

          console.log("If TRUE callback not worked yet!!",$cookies.get('globals') === undefined);

          return !($cookies.get('globals') === undefined);
      };

      // Clear credentials when logout
      service.clearCredentials = function () {
          $rootScope.globals = undefined;
          $cookies.remove('globals');
                        console.log("CLEAN coockies globals",$cookies.get('globals'));

          $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ';
      };

      return service;
  }
  ]);
  ```
- Configuration and run. There we have transitions methods to work:

  ```
  angular.module('myApp', 
  ['ui.router',
  'ngCookies'
  ])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
      function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
          $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/resumen');
          $stateProvider
                  .state("dashboard", {
                      url: "/dashboard",
                      templateUrl: "partials/dashboard.html",
                      controller: "dashCtrl",
                      data: {
                          authRequired: true
                      }
                  })
                  .state("login", {
                      url: "/login",
                      templateUrl: "partials/login.html",
                      controller: "loginController"
                  })
      }])

  .run(['$rootScope', '$transitions', '$state', '$cookies', '$http', 'AuthService',
      function ($rootScope, $transitions, $state, $cookies, $http, AuthService) {

          // keep user logged in after page refresh
          $rootScope.globals = $cookies.get('globals') || {};
          $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + $rootScope.globals;

          $transitions.onStart({
              to: function (state) {
                  return state.data != null && state.data.authRequired === true;
              }
          }, function () {
          console.log("I'm transition.onStart and i'm alive!!!");
              if (!AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
                  return $state.target("autorize");
              }
          });
      }]);
  ```

In dashboard state i use **data** to mark the state only accessible if is authenticated.
Then, on the .run I use the **transitions** to check the autheticated state.

- my controller. $scope.logIn binded to ng-click directive:

  ```
      $scope.logIn = function () {
      AuthService.authenticate($scope.loginInfo.email, $scope.loginInfo.password, function (callback) { 

      console.log("CALLBACK!",callback); //-> callback from server. Always true

      AuthService.setCredentials(callback);   
  });
  ```

  }

All this works as expected, but on **first** ng-click i recieve those: 
[image]

so, .run method with transitions runs BEFORE ng-click callback from server.

On **second** ng-click data was already set in previous ng-click server request so everything works FINE!
[image]

So, the question is how to avoid those terrible two ng-click calling.

documentation for $transition where i took part of code: 
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/1.0.0-alpha.1/interfaces/transition.ihookregistry.html

related post: [angular ui-router login authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537311/angular-ui-router-login-authentication/39617555#39617555)

Comment: Solved using $state.go('target_state'); directive instead of ui-sref