# Using $state.go inside $stateChangeStart causes Infinite loop

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using AngularJS ui-router. I am trying to implement protecting routes for unauthenticated user. I am checking if user is logged in on `$stateChangeStart`. If the user is not logged in then redirect to login state.

But when i am using `$state.go("login")` in `stateChangeStart` handler, the handler code goes in infinite loop and getting console error "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Below is my code:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    var allowedStates = ["signup","confirmaccount","resetPassword"];
    if(!$window.localStorage.getItem('userInfo') && !(allowedStates.includes($state.current.name)))
    {
        $state.go("login");
    }
}
);
```

And below is the screenshot of console error.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prevent the default behavior and check for allowed state without using `$state.current.name` since `toState` is already a parameter to  `$stateChangeStart`

**Update**

I think you need here a `No State Change` logic rather than redirecting to login always.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
  function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    var noChangeStates = ["login", "signup", "confirmaccount", "resetPassword"];
    var noStateChange = noChangeStates.indexOf(toState.name) > -1;

    if (noStateChange) {
      return;
    }

    //Check for Allowed or Not Allowed logic here then redirect to Login
    if (!$window.localStorage.getItem('userInfo')) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go("login")
    }
  }
);
```

Please note, you should also add "login" to No state change

Answer (score 0):

> But when i am using $state.go("login") in stateChangeStart handler, the handler code goes in infinite loop and getting console error "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Looks like you always call `$state.go("login");`

You can check `toState` and `fromState` to avoid calling additional time `$state.go("login");`

Something like:

```
if(!$window.localStorage.getItem('userInfo') 
   && !(allowedStates.includes($state.current.name))
   && fromState.name !== 'login'
){
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go("login");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a stateChange event is not the best way to handle that. Actually, what it does:

- You change state
- Then you check for the authentication.

It would be better to check *before* changing the state. For this, you can use ui-router's [`resolve`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve):

```
$stateProvider
  .state('login', { // Login page: do not need an authentication
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl',
  })
  .state('home', { // Authenticated users only (see resolve)
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl',
    resolve: { authenticate: authenticate }
  });

function authenticate($q, user, $state, $timeout) {
  if (user.isAuthenticated()) {
    // Resolve the promise successfully
    return $q.when()
  } else {
    // The next bit of code is asynchronously tricky.

    $timeout(function() {
      // This code runs after the authentication promise has been rejected.
      // Go to the log-in page
      $state.go('logInPage')
    })

    // Reject the authentication promise to prevent the state from loading
    return $q.reject()
  }
}
```

<sup>See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537311/angular-ui-router-login-authentication).</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried using resolve before. But in that case i must resolve authenticate function for every state. And i don't need that. I want to check it from one place using state event handler.